# Scale of city on map

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out what the scale is for the map that I am designing. The scale is written in the form "1:$N$". By definition, this means that a length of 1 unit on the map corresponds to $N$ units in the real world.

I have a map of a city and I know what the final area of the city on the printed map will be. I also know what the actual area of the city is.

How would I go about finding out what $N$ is?

If the area of the city on the map is $M$ and the actual area of the city is $A$, should $N$ be $\frac{\sqrt{A}}{\sqrt{M}}$ or $\frac{A}{M}$?

I think that by definition $N$ should be the former since the definition talks about lengths.

What am I not getting? This is not homework, just a question that popped up while designing a map.

Comment: The former (with square root). You are not getting nothing.

Comment: You're right. Areas on a 1:10 scale map will be $\frac1{100}$ the real-world areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scale a length by the factor $N$, the area is scaled by the factor $N^2$. So if the area is $M$ on the map, the actual area will be $M N^2=A$.  Now you can caluclate $\frac{A}{M}=N^2$. If you take the square root, you will get $N$.